# Can web browsers navigate up a directory with the URL's location?

Tags: node.js, web, url, server

I'm running a few node.js servers on the same framework right now. Somewhere along the lines of code of the framework I have this little snippet:

```
//...
if (subdomain.staticFolder) {
    let relativePath = subdomain.staticFolder + path.sep + path.normalize(url);
    if (fs.existsSync(relativePath)) {
        let fileStats = fs.statSync(relativePath);
        if (fileStats.isFile()) {
//...
```

This snippet is located inside the handler that manages request traffic. In a nutshell, what it's doing is looking inside a `static/` folder for the domain and seeing if any file matches the request.

My concern is that a malicious user may come along and attempt to gain access to the web server's files, exploiting this lookup method of static files. For example:

`https://www.example.com/../index.js`

`https://www.example.com/../serverStructure.json`

Is this possible, or am I just worrisome? And, if it is possible, what are some potential solutions? Would moving static files to an S3 bucket be viable? Even if it isn't possible, is this still bad backend practice anyway?

Comment: Your browser cannot traverse URI's as a "filesystem", nor is it likely ( unless you deliberately unsecured it ) would your web server allow listing of resource information outside of direct requests for named resources. You can "build an API" to list "filesystem like information" accessible from API calls, and this is basically what services like S3 do. Generally, you are worrying about something that is not enabled in any way, unless you happen to hit `https://www.example.com/static/` and see the listed content of the directory. Usually that's turned off.

Comment: @NeilLunn In this case the `static/` folder is the root directory (`https://www.example.com`), so `static/html/index.html` is equivalent to `https://www.example.com/html/index.html` the way my system is set up.